# Python 3 - Unable to increment global variable inside function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, global-variables, global

I got problem in a technical assessment. The base code(already written) looks someting like this.

```
count=0

def findthesum(a,n):
    global count
    sum=0
    
    '''
    write your code here
    '''
    
    return sum
            
def main():
    global count
    n=5
    a=[1,2,3,4,5]
    print(count)
    print(findthesum(a,n))
    
main()
```

I have to write my logic at specified position inside the code. My code looked something like this.

```
count=0

def findthesum(a,n):
    global count
    sum=0
    l=[]
    for i in range(31):
        l.append(2**i)

    for j in range(n):
        if(a[j] in l):
            count=count+1
            sum=sum+a[j]
    return sum
            
def main():
    global count
    n=5
    a=[1,2,3,4,5]
    print(count)
    print(findthesum(a,n))
    
main()
```

I was unable to increment the value of value of count variable even after declaring it global.

What the issue with this and how to fix this?

Comment: After viewing the answers, I realized that in the main function I was printing the count variable before calling the findthesum function, so it was printing 0. The count variable is actually incrementing inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
count=0

def findthesum(a,n):
    global count
    sum=0
    
    for i in range(n):
        sum+=a[i]
        count+=1
        print(count, end= '')

    print(f'  The sum is: ' + str(sum)) 
            
def main():
    global count
    n=5
    a=[1,2,3,4,5]
    print(count)
    print(findthesum(a,n))
    
main()
```

```
--> '12345  The sum is: 15'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are You trying to sum all the element? If yes, then:

```
count=0
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
n=5
def counting(li, le):
    for i in range(le):
        try:
            count+=li[i-1]
    except:
        pass
    else:
        pass
    return count
counting(a, n)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).